# How does AMP determine the time to load the video when using amp-video in amp-story?

Tags: video, amp-html, amp-story

[Include images & video](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/media/amp_replacements)

> The element loads the video resource specified by the src attribute lazily, at a time determined by AMP.

How does the AMP determine the time to load?

Comment: This is an internal implementation detail of AMP and not something that publishers should rely on, as it can be changed at any time.  Is there a specific reason why you would need to know this?

Comment: Is your question why I would want to know the time to load for AMP pages?

Comment: Rather: amp-story will load videos before they are shown on screen, but the exact timing can depend on a number of different factors.  As a publisher of amp-story documents (or AMP documents generally), this is not something you control directly, nor should you need to worry about.

Comment: Are you saying to the owner of a website that they should not "worry about" how long it takes for videos on their webpage to load?

Comment: Sorry -- there's the matter of *how long* the videos will take to load and, separately, the matter of *when* the video loading will be initiated.  AMP doesn't have much to do with how long the video will take to load, but does do a lot of optimization around when the video should begin to load.  For `amp-story` specifically, I recently gave [a talk](https://youtu.be/MXJGZr2iZa8?t=18m15s) on some of the factors that we currently take into account for determining when videos should begin to load, but there are indeed other factors and they will all likely change over time.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the video. I will check it out.  After some testing, I see that template="fill" with layout="fill" works much better for me than template="fill" + layout+"responsive".  I wish there were code examples in which the video is put into a container that has zero margins.

Comment: Using `template="fill"` should give you a full-bleed video with no margins.  [This section of the getting started tutorial](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/getting_started/visual_story/create_cover_page#fill) explains how this can be used.

Comment: Full bleed can result in not seeing the entire video, as highlighted in this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52727981/amp-story-video-not-displaying-full-picture-width-height-issues].  This quesiton should not be on hold. Also, there should be a tag for amp-video, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rough outline of the video loading strategy used within amp-story can be found in [AMP story's Media Pool documentation](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-story/1.0/media-pool.md).  Additionally, there is [a talk on YouTube](https://youtu.be/MXJGZr2iZa8?t=18m15s) that describes this as well.